# Self-employed: Is the HST portion of my invoice to be included in my taxable income?

Tags: canada, hst, income-tax, self-employment

I am self-employed and charge and receive HST.  I file an HST return so any monies are returned to the government.   Is the HST portion of my invoice to be included in my taxable income?

Answer (score 2):

No. It is recorded in a contra account that washes itself out after each submission. Any monies "earned" in this account would be deemed income.